# Is having a lot of getters & setters a good idea?

Tags: java, android, open-source, getter-setter

When writing an application(in java) that you intend to open source, is it generally a good idea to have a lot of getters & setters and make variables private? More specifically, if that were to be an **android application**, would the answer to the question above still hold?

Edit: If you guys could give me a concrete reason as to why its better, that would be awesome.

Comment: Always holds. Actually make your properties protected whenever you can.

Comment: Why does it always hold?

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has argued that private for DATA is the better choice, not protected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: I usually find *less mutable* objects cleaner to work with -- e.g. don't just add a getter/setter to everything, but rather think about what *needs* to be exposed and how that can done cleanly. (As such, "a lot of getters & setters" sets off my code-smell flags.)

Comment: Also check: http://blog.leocad.io/post/why-you-shouldnt-use-getters-and-setters-on-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are discussing getters & setters in **ANDROID**, check what android documentation tell:-
[**Avoid Internal Getters/Setters**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set)
On Android, this is a bad idea. Virtual method calls are expensive, much more so than instance field lookups. It's reasonable to follow common object-oriented programming practices and have getters and setters in the public interface, but within a class you should always access fields directly.

Answer (score 3):

if all the private variables are expected to be accessed from out side then yes.

Suppose you have certain flags those aren't going to be used from outside then no need of getters/setters for those.

**Also See**

- [**why-use-getters-and-setters**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: I get the second part of your statement. My question is whether its better to have getters/setters instead of accessing variables directly especially if value checking doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes.. always go for getters/setters it has its own advantages , today there is no need suppose tomorrow there need arise..

Comment: You could still directly access the variables without having getters & setters.

Comment: suppose tomorrow you need to add some checks over its value. then it will ***** up the code

Comment: its bettor because at some day, you might need some validation logic on these setters and getters. For example, you want to store date of birth, you can check this condition in setter that it should not be in future.

Answer (score 3):

Lets put it this way, you don't feel any need of having getters/setters and you plan to make your properties non-private. It doesn't appear to be any problem with this approach. But you must ask few questions to yourself.

- Are you having any property whose value should undergo some checking before assignment? (Need for a setter)
- Do you have any mutable property which you don't want to expose as it is? (Need for a getter)

Now, if you think your few properties need getters/setters, but not all. Then I would say create getter/setter for all of them for the sake of consistency. :)

Further see, [**Effective Java 2nd Edition**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683),

- Item 13: Minimize the accessibility of classes and members
- Item 14: In public classes, use accessor methods, not public fields
- Item 15: Minimize mutability
- Item 38: Check parameters for validity
- Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted <s>naming</s> conventions

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Indeed, thanks for the correction.