# What should I use?

Tags: java, variables, methods

We have two different (maybe much more) ways to get an access to `x` variabel:

`example.x` and `example.getX()`

I think first is very fast, but we can't use that in some cases (for instance `e.getX()` when we handle window events).

The question is: should I use only `example.getX()` instead of `example.x` everywhere, or the combination of these ways is better?

Comment: You need to go through Field Encapsulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_encapsulation

Comment: Is speed really an issue here? If not, and I suspect it isn't, then don't let speed be a determining factor.

Comment: Do you think you'll gain a ton of speed by saving one entry in the method stack?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087753/is-having-a-lot-of-getters-setters-a-good-idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  It is considered good practice by most to use **encapsulation** in object oriented design.  This means certain parts of the app only have access to the properties they need, and in very controlled ways--in this case, you would protect access and assignment by using getters and setters.

On the other hand, you could use dot access if you are setting a field in the same class, as long as you don't have a smart setter that does something important.

Note that in order for a class to be considered a Java Bean, it **must** have public setters/getters for every field (among other things). That is only applicable in Java, of course, so it's not really a reason when considering the question in a language agnostic context.